# Count If formula

Tags: excel, count, formula, countif

I need to count how many affiliates each company has.  However, there are numerous affiliate names and companies, so I am getting confused which formula would count the affiliates per company, when the names vary?  I have copied an example below
[image]

Comment: What `COUNTIF()` did you try? It's supposed to be straightforward. Another option is to look into a PivotTable.

Comment: A pivot table will do this.

Comment: Hi there,  

I did a pivot table, but would like a formula so I can drag down and update my lists.

Assume this is fairly straight forward, but I just cant seem to get it right!

Comment: For EG: There are 25 lines with the company 'BDE', and in those 25 lines, there are 5 different affiliate names.  Which formula would be best to just count how many affiliates there are for the company 'BDE'?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to get a **unique** count of the affiliates for each company. One option is to use dynamic array formulas.

For example, `=UNIQUE(Table1[Company])` will return a unique list of companies. In my case, I entered this into column D.

Then I used the following formula in column E:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Affiliate],Table1[Company]=D1)))
```

[image]